# How to call Android contacts list AND Select one phone number from its details screen?

Tags: android

I have read the already posted solutions, but they dont tell how do I use system's contact details screen to select any ONE number to use?
I am developing an sms sending android app which offers to choose contacts of the phone and the number a user wants to use to send to....

So far I have not been able to find anything about choosing any one number. Does it only has to be done programatically? retrieving all numbers from database and sending sms to it?

Regards

Sherry

Comment: Hi, have you got any solution? As I am also looking for the same. I am able to just pick a phone number using `new intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI);` but that screen does not show photos which I need.

Comment: check this link out http://stackoverflow.com/a/9798765/1282492

Answer (score 58):

phew, it took me some time, but i think i have the answer you need (even if it's too late already, but i'll still post it as a reference for others).

in the application i'm currently developing the user may enter a phone number into 
an `EditText` or click on a button and select a person from the phones address book. if the person has more than one phone number, there's a drop down list where he can select exactly one of them.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.contact_picker);

    // this opens the activity. note the  Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT
    // and the intent.setType
    ((Button)findViewById(R.id.pick_person)).setOnClickListener( new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // user BoD suggests using Intent.ACTION_PICK instead of .ACTION_GET_CONTENT to avoid the chooser
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            // BoD con't: CONTENT_TYPE instead of CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE
            intent.setType(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE);
            startActivityForResult(intent, 1);                
        }
    });
}
```

now, as soon as the user selects a contact (and probably chooses one of several phone numbers), you can retrieve the data the normal way:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (data != null) {
        Uri uri = data.getData();

        if (uri != null) {
            Cursor c = null;
            try {
                c = getContentResolver().query(uri, new String[]{ 
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER,  
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE },
                        null, null, null);

                if (c != null && c.moveToFirst()) {
                    String number = c.getString(0);
                    int type = c.getInt(1);
                    showSelectedNumber(type, number);
                }
            } finally {
                if (c != null) {
                    c.close();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

public void showSelectedNumber(int type, String number) {
    Toast.makeText(this, type + ": " + number, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();      
}
```

here's the [documentation for CommonDataKinds.Phone for on dev.android](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.html).

the int "type" tells you the type of number: mobile (2), home (1), work (3), and so on.

note: after the user selects the contact, he gets a spinner of numbers with no indication of the numbers type. that's not really user friendly: if a contact has 5 assigned numbers ... uh, which one of these is the fax number again?

another note: above example needs the sdk > 5 (Android 2.0+), so no 1.6 (=sdk 4). 1.6 has a different api, and if you want to support both versions, read the [article about the contacts API on dev.android](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/contacts.html).

good luck.

disclaimer: i copied most of my code out of the [PickContact.java example](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/content/PickContact.html)

Comment: With ACTION_GET_CONTENT and CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE you sometimes get other apps in the chooser (for instance DropBox and OI File Manager), which can be undesirable.  Using ACTION_PICK and CONTENT_TYPE instead solves this problem.

Answer (score 3):

this code just work fine with me

```
@Override
public void onClick(View arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, Contacts.CONTENT_URI);
    super.startActivityForResult(i, 1001);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    switch (requestCode) {
    case 1001:

        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {

            Cursor s = getContentResolver().query(Phone.CONTENT_URI, null,
                    null, null, null);

        if (s.moveToFirst()) {
                String phoneNum = s.getString(s.getColumnIndex(Phone.NUMBER));
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), phoneNum, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }

        }

        break;

    }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

There is a problem in the accepted answer.
If the number selected contains spaces within it
i.e. 85 29 948789
then it will show only 85 (until first space).

so use the below code to rectify this problem :)

```
Intent intent1 = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
intent1.setType(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_TYPE);
            startActivityForResult(intent1, 1);
```

and in onActivityResult

```
    Uri contactUri = data.getData();

    String[] projection = {ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME};


    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver()
            .query(contactUri, projection, null, null, null);
    cursor.moveToFirst();


    int numberColumn = cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER);
    int nameColumn = cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME);
    String number = cursor.getString(numberColumn);
    String name = cursor.getString(nameColumn);
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this code,i am sure it will work

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            intent.setType(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE);
            startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_CONTACT);
```

Comment: This opens a generic intent, this will work I think, but not the best solution

Answer (score 0):

I've got few codes about this on SO, but in the end I implement code from android guide website https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-common#PickContactDat . I tried the code and I dont need implement any runtime permission request like READ_CONTACTS.

```
static final int REQUEST_SELECT_PHONE_NUMBER = 1;

public void selectContact() {
    // Start an activity for the user to pick a phone number from contacts
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
    intent.setType(CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_TYPE);
    if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
        startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_SELECT_PHONE_NUMBER);
    }
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_SELECT_PHONE_NUMBER && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        // Get the URI and query the content provider for the phone number
        Uri contactUri = data.getData();
        String[] projection = new String[]{CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER};
        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(contactUri, projection,
                null, null, null);
        // If the cursor returned is valid, get the phone number
        if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            int numberIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER);
            String number = cursor.getString(numberIndex);
            // Do something with the phone number
            //...
        }
    }
}
```