# How to show the attached screen to select a number from our application

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity

[image: screen that needs to be displayed to user]

Hello All,

I am working on an android application that sends an sms and allows user to select any number from contact list or call logs, for this i want to show some screen, i.e. attached. that gives option to user to either select number from contact list or from call logs etc. 
Note: the attached image is from samsung galaxy s3 >> compose sms > add sender when we add sender to sms it shows us this screen we want to give user the same options as this one does.

Your help will be appreciated.

Thanks and regards,
Wasif

Comment: follow this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4993063/how-to-call-android-contacts-list-and-select-one-phone-number-from-its-details-s

Comment: ok i am trying will let you know if it fulfills the requirement thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

doesnt work,

i had to create my own views to fetch data from these call logs and contacts to make them select-able in my application.

Thanks and regards,

Answer (score 0):

```
   Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
   intent.setType(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_TYPE);
   startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_CONTACT);
```

Follow this link...

[How can I choose a phone number with Android's contacts dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8612531/how-can-i-choose-a-phone-number-with-androids-contacts-dialog)

Comment: the contact picker shows only the contact list and not the options of the call logs etc as in the image, and Intent.ACTION_PICK only works on contact list and does not return numbers from the call logs...

Comment: Uri myCalls = Uri.parse("content://call_log/calls");
    Cursor c = managedQuery(myCalls, null, null, null, null);

    String num= c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.NUMBER));// for  number

Comment: will it return me the selected no or it will just get numbers from the list to show up