# Android fetch email from contacts doesn't work

Tags: android, android-contacts

I am trying to create a button that opens up contacts and then when you select one contact it fetches the email and adds it to a field in the application.

I've been using the solution found here:

[How to call Android contacts list AND Select one phone number from its details screen?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4993063/how-to-call-android-contacts-list-and-select-one-phone-number-from-its-details-s)

I have changed the code to select the email, but i still get the phone number.

The code is the following:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (data != null) {
        Uri uri = data.getData();

        if (uri != null) {
            Cursor c = null;
            try {
                c = getContentResolver().query(uri, new String[]{ 
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTACT_ID,  
                            ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME,
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.ADDRESS},
                        null, null, null);

                if (c != null && c.moveToFirst()) {
                    long number = c.getLong(0);
                    String type = c.getString(1);
                    String mail = c.getString(2);
                    showSelectedNumber(type, number, mail);
                }
            } finally {
                if (c != null) {
                    c.close();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

public void showSelectedNumber(String number, long type, String email) {
    Toast.makeText(this, type + ": " + number+ ": " + email, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();      
}
```

**EDIT:**
The problem was on the initial query on the onClick call. I am posting the right function

```
private static final int CONTACT_PICKER_RESULT = 1001;
private static final String DEBUG_TAG = null;  
public void doLaunchContactPicker(View view) {  
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
    intent.setType(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_TYPE);
    startActivityForResult(intent, 1);  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry，I do not know why it still get the phone number. But , you can screen the results from contacts  again by regular expression , if match to email address ,save and if not ,remove

I am sorry for my bad english!

Add a method like this:

```
private boolean checkMailAddress(String mailAddress){
final String MAIL_ADDR_REGEX = "([\\w-\\.\\\\+]+)@((\\[[0-9]{1,3}\\.[0-9]{1,3}\\.[0-9]{1,3}\\.)|(([\\w-]+\\.)+))([a-zA-Z]{2,4}|[0-9]{1,3})(\\]?)$";
return mailAddress.matches(MAIL_ADDR_REGEX);
```

}

and I think that you should use "while" , not "if":

```
 while(c != null && c.moveToNext()) {
   long number = c.getLong(0);
   String type = c.getString(1);
   String mail = c.getString(2);
   if(checkMailAddress(mail)){
      showSelectedNumber(type, number, mail);
   }
```

}

Comment: Could you please give me an example?

Comment: I have modfied my answer!