# Calling a Contact picker that show multiple numbers of user contact

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, android-contacts

I see in a app a contactpicker Intent  that show for a contact that have multiple phone number like this:

```
--------------------
Friend 1
Mobile 555567777777
--------------------
Friend 2
Mobile 555567777777
Work cc555567777777
Home 44564646
--------------------
```

I can't find a way to do this only to retrieve one contact and query phone numbers after.

How I can call the intent to do in this way?

Comment: Do you mean you want your contact picker to just show "Friend 1" and not "Friend 2" ?

Comment: no show all number of all contacts sorry for my english, normaly the tutorials says retrive one contact , interact in it to select a phone number, I see app doin this to direct select the wanted number

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8612531/how-can-i-choose-a-phone-number-with-androids-contacts-dialog

Comment: The aswers is something like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4993063/how-to-call-android-contacts-list-and-select-one-phone-number-from-its-details-s#answer-6020669

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setClassName("com.android.contacts","com.android.contacts.activities.PeopleActivity");
    startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: this only let me pick one contact, not pick the phone directly